# Creating sections with perfect height on every screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is for Twitter Bootstrap template:

```
<section>100% Height</section>
<section>100% Height</section>
<section>100% Height</section>
```

Is there a good approach to make each section occupy full view port height irrespective of screen size and browser.

How much *vh* unit will help in this?

Answer (score -1):

```
<section style="height:100%"> </section>
```

should work fine